# VSCode Extension access Language Providers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

On VSCode you can register to provide an specific function of a language server like:

```
vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider
vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider
```

Is there a way from the extension get the list of all the providers and call it's methods to for example get completion items for a given position on the editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these can be called via various `vscode.execute*` commands, for instance `vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider`. See the official docs on [Built-in Commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) for a full list.

As for getting a list of all providers, that seems trickier. You could just try calling a provider and see if you get any results. There's [`getLanguages()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.getLanguages), but that doesn't tell you what providers are registered for a particular language, only that the language itself is registered.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a good amount of time. Will give it a try, seems this is the way to go.